# Session between REST calls with node.js for mobile

Tags: node.js, rest, session, mobile

I have to do registration for a mobile app with node.js (express.js) backend. The registration process involves sevaral steps:
1. provide email
2. verify email
3. provide personal details
4. upload photo

For each of these steps there should be a separate call to the server API ( possibly through REST ).
How to keep the session so that the server knows that the consecutive calls come from the same client ? This is a mobile app so cookie based session won't work I think. Could you guide me somehow ? Is using a JWT token the right way to go ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but...

So here you need to firstly answear a question:
How much time does user have to create such account? For example, if you won't store information that user had started to create account and server restarted ( for whatever reason. eg error ), you will lose this info. So it would be worth to store this in some db.

You can use redis, mongodb, some sql db or just system files (not recommended ) it's up to you.

Assuming you want to persist such info, you can create REST endpoints.
So for example, you can have entry in MongoDB (which basically stores JSON structures).

```
NewAccount { id: <unique_id> , email, info, images }
```

So each endpoint you create will set info in this MongoDB entry.

Example:

1) POST /user/create -> this would create entry in MongodDB
2) PUT /user/create { body: { field: 'email', value: 'p@pp.pl' }}
3) POST /user/create/finish

We have one more question -> how to identify user? You can try to identify it by IP address. If it's mobile app, you have different ways to store info (eg user token) eg:
 https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage

Answer (score -1):

As per your step given :

> sevaral steps: 1. provide email 2. verify email 3. provide personal details 4. upload photo

**1.Register by email and password**

> Suggestion: You need to ask for email and password.

i) When a user enters the email and password check user exists with email if not then send a verified email and redirect to login.

**2. Once User verified. Now user tries to log in.**

i) When a user tries to login check email and password is correct or not.

ii) If correct then **generate JWT Token** on the backend and send back to APP.

ii) Now using JWT Token you can manage the user session on the app.